# Why I can't build https connection with perl and LWP?

Tags: perl, https, lwp

Situation:

> I need to login to a web site with perl script which is a https
>   connection.

Problem I faced:

> I was supposed get a 302 return, however I got 200 with empty
>    tag. I guess I have some proxy issue

What's my question:

> I tried to debug what's causing the problem. I read in some questions
>   that LWP needs  Crypt-SSLeay to make https connection. But I found
>   that LWP can be built with https support, is  Crypt-SSLeay still a
>   necessary?

Comment: How about showing some code?

Comment: don't understand why some one vote close, if you know the answer, give the answer; if you don't, then move on.

Comment: There's more to it than that.  This site is not _primarily_ about answering _your_ question. It's about building a knowledge-base that answers _specific_ questions that might help many other people in the future.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask], and visit [meta] to see the types of discussions around what SO is and isn't.  _"I tried to debug..."_ well, show the code, explain what you did and what happened that you did not expect.  "It didn't work" is insufficient.

Comment: @Jim Garrison You don't need to come to education everyone about the FAQ. There are different types of questions, some you can show in code, some you don't need to. Not every programming question is about coding. If you know the topic, you can provide a very good answer. No one expect you know answer to every question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LWP > 6.00 you need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps) to use https.

However, if you got a response at all the https connection succeeded.  The problem likely lies somewhere else.

You've shown no code, so there's not much more to say.